# C++ Insertion Sort: error when passing values between functions

Tags: c++, sorting, insertion-sort

So I'm coding this program for class, in C++, where I ask the user to input the size of an array, and then the numbers inside of it. Then it asks the user if they wish to have it sorted in ascending, or descending order.

I have tested each of my sorting algorithms individually, and both seem to work flawlessly, however, when I combine them in the sortArr function and pass the values entered by the user from the main function, I get a monstrous error which I cant even decipher. Does anyone know what the problem with my program is?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void sortArr(bool order, int size)
{
    int imax;
    int max;
    int arr[size];

    if (order == true)
    {
        for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            max = arr[0];
            imax = i;

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j] > arr[imax])
                {
                    max = arr[j];
                    imax = j;
                }
            }

            if (imax != i)
            {
                int temp = arr[i];

                arr[i] = arr[imax];
                arr[imax] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    else if (order == false)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            max = arr[0];
            imax = i;

            for (int j = size - 1; j > i; j--)
            {
                if (arr[j] > arr[imax])
                {
                    max = arr[j];
                    imax = j;
                }
            }

            if (imax != i)
            {
                int temp = arr[i];

                arr[i] = arr[imax];
                arr[imax] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    int a;
    bool order;
    string output;

    cout << "Enter the size of the array: ";
    cin >> size;
    if (size < 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: You entered an incorrect value for the array size!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int arr[size];

    cout << "Enter the numbers in the array, seperated by a space, and press enter: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    cout << "Sort in ascending (0) or descending (1) order? ";
    cin >> a;
    if (a == 0)
    {
        order = true;
        cout << "This is the sorted array in ascending order: ";
    }
    else if (a == 1)
    {
        order = false;
        cout << "This is the sorted array in descening order: ";
    }

    output = sortArr(order, size);
    cout << output << endl;

    return 0;
}

cout << "Sort in ascending (0) or descending (1) order? ";
cin >> a;
if(a == 0){
    order = true;
    cout << "This is the sorted array in ascending order: ";
}
else if(a == 1) {
    order = false;
    cout << "This is the sorted array in descening order: ";
}

output = sortArr(order, size);
cout << output << endl;

return 0;
}
```

The error code I'm receiving is this:

```
sortArray1.cpp: In function 'int main()':
sortArray1.cpp:84:9: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'void')
  output = sortArr(order, size);
         ^
sortArray1.cpp:84:9: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from sortArray1.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:546:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
       operator=(const basic_string& __str)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:546:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'const std::basic_string<char>&'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:554:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
       operator=(const _CharT* __s)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:554:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'const char*'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:565:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
       operator=(_CharT __c)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:565:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void' to 'char'
```

Comment: I wasn't sure what part of the code the error was occurring in, so I posted everything, sorry if its a lot.

Comment: Please post the exact error you are trying to fix-- does your program event compile, or does it crash when you run it?

Comment: `int arr[size];`  This is not valid C++ since `size` is a variable.

Comment: Is that really the issue? I have used that before in previous programs. however this is my first attempt at using it while implementing multiple functions.

Comment: The error message says you can't assign a `void` to a `string`. `sortArr` doesn't return anything.

Comment: It's not a runtime error; your code doesn't compile.

Comment: How should I fix this then? The reason I had sortArr set as void is because my instructions said it should have no return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two variables named "arr": one in `main` and one in `sortArr`.

You're reading into the one in `main` and sorting the one in `sortArr` (which is uninitialised, so the program is undefined).

Pass the array as a parameter:

```
void sortArr(bool order, int arr[], int size){
```

There's also the issue of your attempting to assign the non-existent return value (`void`) of `sortArr` to a `std::string`.
Don't do that.

Call the function like this:

```
sortArr(order, arr, size);
```

(`int arr[size];` is also relying on a g++ extension – variable length arrays – which is non-standard. Consider using `std::vector`. It's been around for a couple of decades and is nothing to fear any more.)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried making the changes you suggested, and the program now compiles, but when it tries to print the sorted array, it just outputs:  ▒▒▒
]/{▒▒▒ygX▒▒▒▒
@P▒▒▒3▒▒▒x▒f3▒1▒▒▒gp@X▒▒▒▒
@P▒▒▒
        @H▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒       ▒▒&▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒.▒▒e▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒!▒▒▒▒▒d@@8  h       ▒
@
 ▒f
▒▒9▒▒▒▒▒I▒▒O▒=▒,▒01▒▒▒

Comment: @CalebMoriarty How are you printing it? You need to loop over the array and print each element in turn.

Comment: Oh, haha that was it. I don't know why I didn't think of that before, I should know that by now haha. Thank you for your help :)